# Architecture for manipulation of data from JSON/associative array to dynamically populate drop-down

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, drop-down-menu

This question is more of like requiring an architecture and correct approach, then actual code.
Stating it so that people shouldn't flag it as "We cannot code for you..." etc.

I get a response from the API in JSON which I converted to an associated array using json_decode as:

```
Array
(
    [statusCode] => 200
    [data] => Array
        (
            [objects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => deals
                    [1] => contacts
                    [2] => accounts
                )

            [deals] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dealName
                    [1] => ApprovedBy
                    [2] => ApprovedDate
                    [3] => CloseDate
                )

            [contacts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => contectName
                    [1] => email
                    [2] => firstName
                    [3] => lastName 
                )

            [accounts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => accountName
                    [1] => creationDate
                    [2] => ApprovedDate
                    [3] => accountNumber
                )
        )

)
```

So the structure is as:
In response's data array against key "**objects**", I have an array of objects i.e deals, contacts, accounts.
And for each element in the objects array as the key, an array of fields exist.

1. I have to show the objects in a drop down say "**Objects**" and upon selection of a value say "**deals**" I want to show elements of deals array in a second drop-down "**Fields**".
2. [DONE] *Also for the options in the dropdowns, values should be the same as actual elements and not numeric values.
   json_decode(string, true) gives associated array but with numeric keys. So keys should be same as their associated values like:*

   [deals] => deals
   [contacts] => contacts
   [accounts] => accounts
3. In the view, I have a table with a number of rows, each row having its own pair of these drop-downs.
   If each row has its own drop-down, then I also have to take care avoiding updating second drop-down in wrong places. As each drop-down is an array of objects[] & object_fields[], should I use the index of this array in DOM, get next sibling in DOM, or to assign a unique id to each row for the population of correct drop-down at correct row?

How should I achieve these, what should be the correct way?
I cannot use ajax/getJson() as to reduce the number of requests to API and I do have all the required data available. Just need to use it but needed meticulous approach regarding architecture.

Should I pass on Json object to view and process it in javascript in view? Will this be a better approach?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Point 2 of the question is DONE.

Comment: Can you make a demo with dropdown which gives you numeric value ? you can set value of dropdown `<option value="display_value">display_value</option>` ?

Comment: This was the drop-down previously with **objects** array for options https://jsfiddle.net/42Ljho3t/