# How to replace numeric keys in associative array with their corresponding values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I do have following associative multidimensional array available after json_decode(string, true).

```
Array
(
    [statusCode] => 200
    [data] => Array
        (
            [objects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => deals
                    [1] => contacts
                    [2] => accounts
                )

            [deals] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dealName
                    [1] => ApprovedBy
                    [2] => ApprovedDate
                    [3] => CloseDate
                )

            [contacts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => contectName
                    [1] => email
                    [2] => firstName
                    [3] => lastName 
                )

            [accounts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => accountName
                    [1] => creationDate
                    [2] => ApprovedDate
                    [3] => accountNumber
                )
        )

)
```

It want to replace numeric keys with their corresponding values in arrays like:

```
[deals] => deals
[contacts] => contacts
[accounts] => accounts
```

What I tried so far?

```
$finalIOArray = array();
$integrationObjectsArray = $response['data']['objects']; 
foreach($integrationObjectsArray as $integrationObject){ 
   $finalIOArray[$integrationObject] = $integrationObject; 
}
```

This is for only the **objects** array in the main data array. But I want to replace keys with values in all the sub-arrays in the main data array.

Comment: what have you tried, this isn't code my stuff for me site.

Comment: What I did is:

$finalIOArray = array();
$integrationObjectsArray = $response['data']['objects'];
foreach($integrationObjectsArray as $integrationObject){
                  $finalIOArray[$integrationObject] = $integrationObject;
              } 
But if I follow this approach, I manually have to treat each array in data array.

Comment: Please edit your original question with this info.

Comment: I don't see why you need the `objects` entry at all; it is duplicate information for what is already represented by the other keys in the same array. Also I don't understand why `deals`, `contacts` and `accounts` are plural words when you only store one item in their values.

Comment: **objects** are being populated in a drop-down as its possible options.
And upon selection of any object from the 1st drop-down, a second drop-down is populated with fields associated with that object.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128410/architecture-for-manipulation-of-data-from-json-associative-array-to-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
foreach($arr["data"] as $key=>&$data){
  $new = array();
  foreach($data as $key2=>$value){
    $new[$value] = $value;
  }
  $data = $new;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/858599

Comment: It is not the required output.

Comment: Yes, something like this.
This enlightened me with the idea to manipulate the main data array. Let me try that.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I wanted to process all in one go. Please update the original answer with this update so that I can accept it.

Comment: have updated my ans. Just a curiosity where you need to update array like this, I means in which code ?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128410/architecture-for-manipulation-of-data-from-json-associative-array-to-dynamically

This question was the sub-question (point 2) in that, In which I wanted a correct way and direction. That was my use case if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

here's a recursive solution to the problem

```
function updateArray(array $data)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_integer($key) && is_string($value)) { // key is integer and value is string
            $result[$value] = $value; // update the key
        } elseif (is_array($value)) { // value is array
            $result[$key] = updateArray($value); // recurse
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value; // leave key/value alone
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(updateArray($arr));
```

Comment: Let me try this, seems elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I modify my code to suits your needs, please, try it.

```
$data = [];
foreach($arr["data"] as $key => $example) {
    $new = [];
    foreach($example as $value) {
        $new[$value] = $value;
    }
    $data[$key] = $new;
}
$arr["data"] = $data;
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I add $key's to keep your original keys like objects, deals, contacts, accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner and more direct method than the others on offer.  Use array_combine to bulk reassign keys using values from the subarray.

In my method using foreach, the `&` before `$data` means "passing by reference" .  http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php This effectively allows the modification of the original array data without writing the keys that lead to the specific deep element.

Code:

```
$arr =  Array
(
    "statusCode" => 200,
    "data" => Array
        (
            "objects" => Array
                (
                    "0" => deals,
                    "1" => contacts,
                    "2" => accounts
                ),

            "deals" => Array
                (
                    "0" => dealName,
                    "1" => ApprovedBy,
                    "2" => ApprovedDate,
                    "3" => CloseDate
                ),
            "contacts" => Array
                (
                    "0" => contectName,
                    "1" => email,
                    "2" => firstName,
                    "3" => lastName 
                ),
            "accounts" => Array
                (
                    "0" => accountName,
                    "1" => creationDate,
                    "2" => ApprovedDate,
                    "3" => accountNumber
                )
        )
);
foreach($arr["data"] as &$data){
     $data=array_combine($data,$data);
}
var_export($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (
   'statusCode' => 200,
  'data' => 
  array (
    'objects' => 
    array (
      'deals' => 'deals',
      'contacts' => 'contacts',
      'accounts' => 'accounts',
    ),
    'deals' => 
    array (
      'dealName' => 'dealName',
      'ApprovedBy' => 'ApprovedBy',
      'ApprovedDate' => 'ApprovedDate',
      'CloseDate' => 'CloseDate',
    ),
    'contacts' => 
    array (
      'contectName' => 'contectName',
      'email' => 'email',
      'firstName' => 'firstName',
      'lastName' => 'lastName',
    ),
    'accounts' => 
    array (
      'accountName' => 'accountName',
      'creationDate' => 'creationDate',
      'ApprovedDate' => 'ApprovedDate',
      'accountNumber' => 'accountNumber',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Or if you prefer functional iteration, this provides the same output.

```
$arr["data"]=array_map(function ($a){return array_combine($a,$a);},$arr["data"]);
var_export($arr);
```

Comment: Nice & concise.  Can you explain a little about ampersand sign before enumeration variable $data? Thanks